# Rails obtain id in controller action create after build

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I am trying to obtain the id after the object is build. How do i obtain the id in the following case:

```
  def create
    @event = current_customer.events.build(params[:event])
    @ev = Event.find(@event)
```

I am trying to use so i can save the event.id into a specific locations but i am not sure how to grab the id of it build is it possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you use `#build`, it is the same as `#new` so it doesn't create an object therefore no id is assigned.  You should use `#create`

Comment: If you need to do something with the id every time, consider using `after_create`